# MinIO | Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3, minio, httpconnection

Goal: download all files within a folder, in a MinIO bucket.

Since I want to dynamically download all files in a folder, I use:

```py
objs = list(client.list_objects(bucket, recursive=True)).sort()
```

That way, I can iterate over each file name for download using:

```
for o in objs:
    obj = client.get_object(bucket, o)
```

Downloading a specified file also fails:

```py
obj = client.get_object(bucket, 'industry/gri/esg/ESG_COMP.csv')
```

Code:

```py
from sdg.datasource.MinioConn import MinioConn

client = MinioConn().client()

bucket = 'synthetic-data-gen'
obj = client.get_object(bucket, 'industry/gri/esg/ESG_COMP.csv')
print('###')
print(obj)
objs = list(client.list_objects(bucket, recursive=True)).sort()

dfs = []
for o in objs:
    obj = client.get_object(bucket, o)
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(obj).iloc[:, 0].tolist())  # 1 column csvs
```

MinioConn:

```py
from minio import Minio

class MinioConn:
    def __init__(self,
                 host='foo.bar.foo.bar.com:9000',
                 access_key='CENSORED', secret_key='CENSORED',
                 secure=False):
        self.host = host
        self.access_key = access_key
        self.secret_key = secret_key
        self.secure = secure

    def client(self):
        return Minio(self.host, self.access_key, self.secret_key,
                     secure=self.secure)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc6f4ee17f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/repo/project/foo/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sdg.sdg import generate_data
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/repo/project/foo/sdg.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sdg.industry.gri.generator import Generator as GRIGenerator
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/repo/project/foo/industry/gri/generator.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Generator:
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/repo/project/foo/industry/gri/generator.py", line 346, in Generator
    dfs = get_esgs()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/repo/project/foo/industry/gri/generator.py", line 61, in get_esgs
    obj = client.get_object(bucket, 'industry/gri/esg/ESG_COMP.csv')
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/minio/api.py", line 1151, in get_object
    return self._execute(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/minio/api.py", line 394, in _execute
    region = self._get_region(bucket_name, None)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/minio/api.py", line 461, in _get_region
    response = self._url_open(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/minio/api.py", line 266, in _url_open
    response = self._http.urlopen(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='foo.bar.foo.bar.com', port=9000): Max retries exceeded with url: /synthetic-data-gen?location= (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc6f4ee17f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

implies that DNS resolution on the host name (`foo.bar.foo.bar.com`) failed. You likely need to check your DNS configuration or fix the host name if it is incorrect.